# Is it possible to use itertools.permutations() to print permutations in real time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I'm writing a simple script that prints all permutations of an input string:

```
import itertools
inputstring = input("What is your request?")
print("Calculating permutations...")
permlist = (list(itertools.permutations(inputstring)))
for x in range (len(permlist)):
  print ("%s is word #%s"%("".join(permlist[x]),x+1))
```

But this code must first calculate all permutations, then print them after it is finished. Is there any way to print the output strings in real time instead of at the end of the calculation?

Comment: Just loop over the `itertools.permutations(inputstring)`. It's an iterator object and will produce the permutations on demand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the call to `list` which is consuming all permutations.  Instead, just iterate the *iterator* object which is returned from itertools directly:

```
perms = itertools.permutations(inputstring)

for i, perm in enumerate(perms, 1):
    word = "".join(perm)
    print("%s is word #%d" % (word, i))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful response!